# Scoring in Match phrase and Match query not as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am little confused how scoring is done in matchphrase and match query by seeing my results

For Match Phrase
I have query like below

```
sd.Query(q =>    
 q.MatchPhrase(m => m  
 .Field(p => p.title)  
 .Query("Test Article in Credit")    
  ));
```

the reults obtained are as below
a. document with "Test Article in Credit - Consumer" score 12.64
b. document with "Test Article with Credit -X"       score 12.64
c. document with "Test Article in Credit - XYZ"      score 10.92
d. document with "Test Article in Credit"            score 10.22
e. document with "Test Article in Credit -Z"         score 09.40

first two are from different index and last three from different index

According to me the fourth one should have high  score and second should have lowest.
I am using standard Analyzer

Similarly my match query does same
document with title"Test" is having high score than 
document with title"Test Article in Credit"

I know scoring happens for more relevant articles based on
frequency of term appearing , length of text.

How can i restructure my query to give documents in right order?

Comment: Relevancy scores are calculated _per shard_ so can vary both within an index with more than one shard and across indices. With _many_ documents and sensible routing however, relevancy score differences diminish across shards. A rescore query can help to smooth differences when dealing with a small number of documents.

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely hard from here to say why your expectations don't match up with the results but I will do you one better: you can find out yourself by using [the Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)